# How to create a parent child collection where the output will be in hierarchical structure using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop

I want to create a hierarchical structure in VB.NET like given below

```
<Parent>
  <Child1><Child1 />
  <Child2>
     <Subchild1 />
     <Subchild2 />
<Child2 />     
</Parent>
```

I created the entity class and collection classes for `parent`, `child1`, `child2`, `subchild1` and `subchild2`. I need to pass the parent collection class instance to a XML serializer class to generate a hierarchical node structure as given above. I am not sure how to go about. Please give me a sample.

Entities:

```
Public class Parent
  Public property FirstName as string
  Public property LastName as string
End Class

Public Class Child1
  Public property Color as string
End class

Public Class Child2
  Public property Color as string
End class

Public Class SubChild1
  Public property FirstName as string
End Class

Public Class SubChild2
  Public property FirstName as string
End Class

Collection Class:
Public class ParentS
  Public Function Add(objrow as Parent, byref skey as object) as Parent
```

Should I need to add child class as property to the parent class? how to do that and create a structure as given above. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it like this:

```
Public Class Node

  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String

  Private _childNodes As New List(Of Node)

  Public Property ChildNodes As List(Of Node)
  Get
     Return _childNodes
  End Get
  Set
     _childNodes = value
  End
  End Property

End Class
```

**Usage**

```
Dim parent As New Node
parent.FirstName = "John"
parent.LastName = "Doe"

Dim child_1 As New Node()
child_1.FirstName = "Jane"
child_1.LastName = "Doe"
parent.ChildNodes.Add(child_1)
```

### update

```
Public Class Employee

  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String

End Class

Public Class Department

  Private _employees As New List(Of Employee)
  Private _subDepartments As New List(Of Department)

  Public Property SubDepartments As List(Of Department)
  Get
     Return _subDepartments
  End Get
  Set
     _subDepartments = value
  End
  End Property

  Public Property Employees As List(Of Employee)
  Get
     Return _employees
  End Get
  Set
     _employees = value
  End
  End Property

End Class
```

**Usage**

```
Dim dept As New Department
dept.Name  = "Accounting"

Dim subDept1 As New Department()
subDept1.Name = "Audit"

dept.SubDepartments.Add(subDept1)

Dim employee1 As New Employee()
employee1.FirstName = "John"
employee1.LastName = "Doe"

dept.Employees.Add(employee1)
```

Hope that helps! This can be refactored further but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand what you have given. But my child class has different property like(department is my parent class and employee is my child class,  one to many relationship).Do i need to add employee class properties to department class as you have given? becoz i dont see anywhere child class is getting instantiated in your answer? Since i have 4 child collection classes with many properties that will be listed under the parent class in realtime scenario. Also i have given addrow method for looping the nodes for recursive records. Pls clarify